# xsl param fails in PHP 5.3x

Tags: php, xslt, php-5.3

I have an  in PHP 5.3 that is failing when **something** is its contents.

For context I do a XSL transformation on one DOMDocument and insert the results as a parameter into another DOMDocument that is then transformed. This has worked fine until now.

```
<h5>lets see: <xsl:value-of select="string-length($content)" /></h5>
```

returns 0.

```
$content
```

is the param name.

In my PHP I can get this to work a thousand time elsewhere but for some reason on this occasion it only fails on inserting circa one thousand names into an HTML table. If I swap the names for something else e.g. the autoincrement ID then it works fine.

I have no double/single quote issues, as everything is run through a cleanup utility and I have manually gone through the data and removed everything but alpha numeric characters.

Is there a max lenght/size with xsl param's?

Comment: did you ever resolve this? I think I am experiencing a similar issue.

Comment: Did you `<xsl:call-template name="..."> <xsl:with-param name="content" select="..."/></xsl:call-template/>`, or in other words did you call your template with the required param?